# Подскажите как background-color вынести на передний план? Чтобы сделать затемнение (в 50% черного)

Tags: css, z-index

```css
.slider-1:img {
  padding-top: 20px;
  max-height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 50;
}

.slick-center {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-1 single-item">
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide-block slick-slide slick-center">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide-block slick-slide">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не думаю, что в данном примере поможет z-index
Вот разные варианты:

opacity - для всех блоков, кроме центрального

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-center) img {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

Поиграйтесь с фильтрами, таким же селектром как и выше

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-center) img {
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}
```

или дайте фон через :before

```
.slick-slide:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.slick-center:before {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для затемнения не нужно никакого `z-index`-а просто добавьте **opacity**

```css
.slider-1 img {
  padding-top: 20px;
  max-height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity:0.5;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position:relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

.slick-center {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-1 single-item">
  <div class="slick-slide">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide-block slick-slide slick-center">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slide-block slick-slide">
    <img src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Задача состоит в том чтобы сделать верхний и нижний блоки с затемнением на 50% черного. А тут получилось прозрачность среднего

Comment: задача состояло сделать затемнения .никакого 50% в вопросе не было.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил вопрос(